# Compactness of a sum of spheres in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

Let $S(a,t)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : d_e(a,x)=t\}$ be $n$-dimensional sphere in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\cal{T}_e)$ (natural, euclidean topology). Then for $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r:A\longrightarrow (0,\infty)$ let $S(A)=\bigcup\{S(a,r(a)):a\in A\}$.

How to prove that if $A$ is compact and $r$ is a continuous function, then $S(A)$ is also a compact set? Undoubtedly continuous image of compact set is compact and then so is sphere. But I still can't infer from this data, that $S(A)$ is compact. I know for sure it is bounded, but why is it also closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x_n \in S(a_n, r(a_n))$, since you already know $S(A)$ is bounded, there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which convergs to $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$a_{n_k}$ is a sequence in the compact set $A$, so there is a subsequence $a_{n_{k_l}}$ which converges to $a \in A$

Then we can see $x \in S(a, r(a))$, i.e. $d(a,x) = r(a)$ by sending $l$ to infinity in $d(a_{n_{k_l}}, x_{n_{k_l}}) = r(a_{n_{k_l}})$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Consider instead a function $S(0,1) \times A \to \mathbb R^n$, defined by $(s, a) \mapsto s\cdot r(a)+a$.